# In Angular 5, How do I prevent a component from invoking its subscription twice when the components has been contained twice within another component?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 5, How do I prevent a component from invoking its subscription twice when the components has been contained twice within another component?
For example, I have a NavMenuComponent, and within the template, I have a cart contained twice

```
        <!-- cart 1 in nav fixed -->
    <nav-menu-cart class="toolbar-item" *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()"></nav-menu-cart>


        <!-- cart 2 in nav scrolled -->
    <nav-menu-cart class="toolbar-item" *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()"></nav-menu-cart>
```

And, Contained within the NavMenuCartComponent, the ctor has a subscription as follows

```
    this.subscription = cartConnectorService.cartItemAdded$.subscribe(
  newCartItem => {
    console.log("in cartConnectorService.cartItemAdded$.subscribe");
    this.saveCartWithNewItem(newCartItem);
  });
```

saveCartWithNewItem ultimately invokes the CartService.saveCart(cart)

The problem is that the saveCartWithNewItem function is invoked twice, whereas it needs to be invoked only once. (log screenshot below showing its been invoked twice)
[image: log of subscription]

Someone may ask, Why is your NavMenuCartComponent responsible for making the call to saveCartWithNewItem? Why not have the data contained within say, a CartService, and simply refresh the data in the NavMenuCartComponent in the subscription instead? The reason is that the CartService is only responsible for HTTP calls, not storing data, at this time.

Also, the component initially responsible for invoking the Observable is ProductsGridComponent. Which uses the connector service CartConnectorService.

Fundamentally, what I want to happen is, I want to allow the ProductsGridComponent to allow adding items to the cart. And, given that the NavMenuComponent has two NavMenuCartComponent's, I need the data to be updated in those, as well as in persistance layer (through the service). My implementation was to use the  CartConnectorService to ensure that this happens, but now I have this duplicate invokation issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only way I can see around it is creating an `@Input` on your component specifying whether or not to invoke `saveCartWithNewItem`, so that you can tell one of them to save and not the other. Feels a bit messy though.

Comment: Can you provide some code to support this possibility?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `@Input` on the `NavMenuCartComponent`, that tells it whether or not to `saveCartWithNewItem`.

In the `NavMenuCartComponent`:

```
@Input callSaveCart: boolean;

//...

ngOnInit() {
    // ...

    if(callSaveCart) {
        this.subscription = cartConnectorService.cartItemAdded$.subscribe(newCartItem => {
            console.log("in cartConnectorService.cartItemAdded$.subscribe");
            this.saveCartWithNewItem(newCartItem);
        });
    }
}
```

Then, in your HTML, specify the one you want to save:

```
     <!-- cart 2 in nav scrolled -->
     <nav-menu-cart class="toolbar-item" [callSaveCart]="true" ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()"></nav-menu-cart>
```

Comment: almost works. So I upvoted. Only issue now is that the NavMenuCartComponent has   navMenuCart: ICart = {
    buyerId: '',
    items: []
  }; and this actually needs to be updated after the save, any ideas here? With the update you mentioned above, only one of the templates gets its data updated.

Comment: @joey If the two components need to share state, then that shared state belongs in a service

Comment: I appreciate the help. Ill take a look into that since that changes things quite a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution I can think of:

```
if (!this.subscription) {
  this.subscription = cartConnectorService.cartItemAdded$.subscribe(
    newCartItem => {
      console.log("in cartConnectorService.cartItemAdded$.subscribe");
      this.saveCartWithNewItem(newCartItem);
    });
}
```

Comment: this wont work, the ctor is invoked twice, and the subscription is not set until below your conditional, therefore this.subscription.unsubscribe(); will never happen. I just tested this.